# How to enable eager mode in tf.data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

For a project, I am using tf.data.Dataset to write the input pipeline.
The input is an image RGB
The label is a list of 2D coordinates of of objects in the image that used to generate a heatmap

Here is a MWE to reproduce the problem.

```
 def encode_images(image, label):
        """

        Parameters
        ----------
        image
        label

        Returns
        -------

        """
        # load image
        # here the normal code
        # img_contents = tf.io.read_file(image)
        # # decode the image
        # img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_contents, channels=3)
        # img = tf.image.resize(img, (256, 256))
        # img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)

        # this is just for testing
        image = tf.random.uniform(
            (256, 256, 3), minval=0, maxval=255, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, seed=None, name=None
        )
        return image, label

    def generate_heatmap(image, label):
        """

        Parameters
        ----------
        image
        label

        Returns
        -------

        """

        start = 0.5
        sigma=3
        img_shape = (image.shape[0] , image.shape[1] )
        density_map = np.zeros(img_shape, dtype=np.float32)
        for center_x, center_y in label[0]:
            for v_y in range(img_shape[0]):
                for v_x in range(img_shape[1]):
                    x = start + v_x
                    y = start + v_y
                    d2 = (x - center_x) * (x - center_x) + (y - center_y) * (y - center_y)
                    exp = d2 / (2.0 * sigma**2)
                    if exp > math.log(100):
                        continue
                    density_map[v_y, v_x] = math.exp(-exp)
        return density_map


    X = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png"]
    y = [[[2, 3], [100, 120], [100, 120]],
         [[2, 3], [100, 120], [100, 120], [2, 1]],
         [[2, 3], [100, 120], [100, 120], [10, 10], [11, 12]],
         [[2, 3], [100, 120], [100, 120], [10, 10], [11, 12], [10, 2]],
         [[2, 3], [100, 120], [100, 120]]
         ]
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, tf.ragged.constant(y)))
    dataset = dataset.map(encode_images, num_parallel_calls=8)
    dataset = dataset.map(generate_heatmap, num_parallel_calls=8)
    dataset = dataset.batch(1, drop_remainder=False)
```

The problem is that in `generate_heatmap()` function, I have used numpy array to modify the elements by indices which is ~ not possible in tensorflow. I try to iterate over the label tensor which is not possible in tensorflow till now. The other things is that the eager mode seems not enabled in  `tf.data.Dataset`!! Any suggestion to deal with that! I think in pytorch such code can be done quickly without suffering :) !

Comment: Don't condemn me if I am wrong, but I believe it's tf.executing_eagerly(). If you use Jupyter or Colab, it's automatically enabled but that's how you manually enable it.

Comment: Eager execution does not work in the map function.

Comment: @AniketBote any deal with this ?

Comment: to wrap your python or numpy function in TensorFlow operation,try using [tf.py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function)

Comment: Your `generate_heatmap` function contains errors. See [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eqVf7HNCU4QGPkkjU-aFkmOXWkiAtBD9?usp=sharing)

Comment: @AniketBote, in your example you can just convert label to a list  and change label[0] in the generate_heatmap to label. In your example, the eager mode is activated